# How to add a datefield attribute with integer attribute using ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails model with two attributes, one is a datetime field and the other is an integer. I'm trying to add a scope using both these fields & it gives me incorrect results.

```
ModelName.where("model.created_at + model.hours > ?", Time.now)
```

Model.created_at is of class `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` and Model.hours is `Integer`.

Sample data

```
created_at: Mon, 28 Nov 2022 10:16:39.095488000 UTC +00:00,
hours: 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PostgreSQL, I think you can use something like:

```rb
ModelName.where("created_at + interval '1 hour' * hours > ?", Time.now)
```

For MySQL:

```rb
ModelName.where("DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL hours hour) > ?", Time.now)
```

Comment: Not Postgres. MySQL :/

Comment: @PreethiKumar answer updated with MySQL solution